# Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS customization applies after login only

Tags: multiple-monitors, customization, desktop-background, unity-greeter

I have problems with some customization of my OS (Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS).

I changed wallpapers and monitor position (reversed them) using GUI tools (**Appearance & Displays** in **System settings**) and everything turned out without any problems or errors.

But every day, when I power on or reboot PC, on login screen I see the classic theme, and mouse works as if the right monitor is the left and so on.

After login all works (and looks) right.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using user settings, instead of using them globally and they apply only after logging in with the specific user. Put the same settings in your display manager settings and everything will be fine.

Edit: I guess you are using lightdm as it's the default display manager for ubuntu, in that case you can put your `monitors.xml` in `/var/lib/lightdm/.config/` so your monitors resolution and order will work at the  login screen.
As for the wallpaper on your login screen check this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449677/how-do-i-set-the-lightdm-wallpaper-in-ubuntu-14-04).

Comment: And how can i do this? Trying to start unity-control-center from terminal with sudo, but don't think that it is a good idea

Comment: You should tell us what display manager, graphic environment you are using in order to help you.

Comment: Default Ubuntu with Unity (if another, i would be write about it in main message). I find how i can change global setting to the monitors, but about wallpapers question is still open

Comment: I edited my answer, so it answers all your questions.

Comment: Thanks for help, @asenm! I cannot add you plus to rep now, but you deserved it, friend!

Comment: about monitors: for my great sorrow, this solution doesn't work with 16.04.3 ubuntu. peharps, it's ok for previous version, but for me adds more lags on greetings screen