# Unity greeter does not display custom wallpaper

Tags: 14.04, lightdm, login-screen, desktop-background, unity-greeter

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit .  I know this question has popped up many times but I want to make it very clear that none of the posts helped me a bit.

**my Problem**:
I am unable to get my custom wallpaper stored at /home/sudeepto/Pictures on the Ubuntu login screen . The screen shows me purple background and upon giving login credentials the graphics gets really scrambled for a while and then I can use my system just fine.

I guess since most of the articles are not Ubuntu 14.04 based, I am having such problems.

**Things that I tried**:

I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140910/unity-greeter-background-not-changing-for-users-automatically-after-upgrade) post on askbuntu . I tried both the suggestions but no luck.

I don't know how to take screenshot of unity-greeter, otherwise I would have given links to my login screen as well.

Please tell me what should I do next to solve this problem which I never faced in previous versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: ive encountered this before i cannot change the background of lightdm greeter, but since my system update on 07/04/14.. all be seem fine now.. when i change my desktop wallpaper, it shows also in lightdm greeter automatically.

Comment: What was installed? What changed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To change the background of the login screen (based on [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/334992/270074) answer):

```
sudo -i
xhost +SI:localuser:lightdm
su lightdm -s /bin/bash
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-user-backgrounds 'false'
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter background 'path-to-image'
exit
```

This will only change the background of the login screen. If you also want to change the background of your lock screen, you should also execute the following commands as each user you want to change the background for:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-user-backgrounds 'false'
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter background 'path-to-image'
```

I can confirm this is working on 14.04 LTS.

---

By setting `draw-user-backgrounds` to `false` you can set a custom background.

Obviously you should replace `path-to-image` by an absolute path to the image you want to use. Make sure the `lightdm` user has read permissions for this file.

---

**Optional tweaks you might like**

You can also change the background color which you'll see in a flash (default purple) before your background is loaded. To do this, execute the following command after the other `gsettings` commands (this will change the color to black):

```
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter background-color '#000000'
```

And you can disable the dots on the login screen by executing the following:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-grid 'false'
```

And also remove the greeter sound

```
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter play-ready-sound 'false'
```

Comment: So do i need to do apply these settings for every wallpaper that I use other than the default ones ??

I mean is there a way so that whenever I add wallpapers inside the /home/sudeepto/Pictures folder it automatically apply the aforementioned settings for them as well??

Comment: If you want to change the wallpaper, you'll have to execute the commands again, or you can just overwrite your last background image with a new image.

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't understood the difference between overwriting the image and changing it .

Suppose I chose a different wallpaper from the *Pictures* folder, so do I need to execute all the above commands again or changing the wallpaper will automatically set my login screen to the new wallpaper.

Comment: If you set your wallpaper like this, Unity will open the image (for example `/home/sudeepto/Pictures/bg.jpg`) every time, so you can just overwrite `bg.jpg` and Unity will load your new `bg.jpg`. If you want to use the same background as your desktop's background you should set `draw-user-backgrounds` to `true`, but this is the default setting so then I wonder why you asked this question.

Comment: Okay, Yeah I wanted to know how can we add a different as well as the same wallpaper as the desktop background since I'm having problems's with the login screen only showing purple screen. Anyways, can you please tell me what do you  mean by this line??

**Make sure the lightdm user has read permissions for this file.** ??

Comment: If `lightdm` (the user running the login screen) doesn't have permission to read the image file, it can't be loaded so you won't see it. Right click your image, choose `Properties`, click `Permissions`, at `Others` set `Access` to `Read-only`.

Comment: Okay, the Access for the image was *None*. Now I changed it to *Read-only*. Should I need to repeat the commands now ?? Or will it   work just fine ??

Comment: It should work fine. If it doesn't you only won't see a background. Just log in as usual and try again.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. i didn't knew about the Permissions thing . So I guess I will have to explicitly set the Others access to Read-only :)

I am adding your response an my answer :)

Answer (score 10):

In current Ubuntu 14.04 (October 2014), there is no need to hack `gsettings` manually. If the wallpaper file is available to others (read permissions), the greeter automagically displays everyone's background as you select the login name.

My wallpaper lives inside the Dropbox folder which has the permissions `drwx------` and thus the greeter can't access it. Copying it to the pictures folder which has permissions `drwxr-xr-x` and using it from that folder solves the issue. Probably linking via `ln -s` works as well (although I didn't try).

You can check the permissions of everything in a folder using the `-l` option for `ls`.

Comment: PERFECT! Just right click the photo you used as wallpaper, change its permissions to allow read and write for everyone. I changed the permissions for my Pictures folder where my wallpapers are kept, so now all the wallpapers display on my lockscreen. Awesome!

Comment: Note that this doesn't work if your home directory is encrypted (at least, I tried the above but it didn't work). What worked form me: http://askubuntu.com/a/123554/22147