# Add custom indicator to lightdm-slick-greeter

Tags: login, laptop, lightdm, battery, indicator

I'm trying to add a custom indicator to the lightdm-slick-greeter I'm using.
I have 2 batteries in my laptop and would like to be able to see both batteries on my loginscreen. I looked through a few config files however I wasn't able to find a way to add such an indicator.

Comment: I'm still searching for an efficient way to set up the slick-greeter too. I think you'll need to edit dconf settings to do so. Here I've found an example of dconf editing for the background setting: https://askubuntu.com/questions/455849/unity-greeter-does-not-display-custom-wallpaper/455857#455857

Comment: Since it's related with my post where I ask for configuring the slick-greeter with a GUI tool. Here's the link to it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1440796/how-to-setup-and-customise-ubuntu-cinnamons-slick-greeter-in-a-gui-menu