# Unity-greeter not using personal wallpaper in Bionic

Tags: desktop-background, 18.04, unity-greeter

It just displays the default Ubuntu background instead of the one I set. I didn't have the issue with 17.10 before upgrading.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and ultimately found the answer here:-
 [Unity greeter background not changing for users automatically after upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140910/unity-greeter-background-not-changing-for-users-automatically-after-upgrade)
This was actually an old post for 12.04 and I used dconf-editor to make the changes,rather than gsettings set, but the gist of it is:-
*com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-user-backgrounds* should be set to *true* (which it was on my setup)
*gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active* should be set to *true* (it was set to false on my setup)
Please note that I had to do this for **all** of the users on the PC. Does anyone know if it is possible to set this for all users as a default?
Anyway, hope this helps :-)
Mick